# How do I make a C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just downloaded unity today and I started watching tutorials, but when they press new script on a component they can select languages, for me it just doesn't show it.
I suspect its because I didn't choose a language on installation.

I've tried to search for an answer but I can't seem to find one.
**P.S.**
I want to add c#

Comment: Unity currently only supports c#. Any script you add will be using c#.

Comment: But when I go to add a script it shows me the insert name bar but not the select language and then the “Create and Add” button is just greyed out

Comment: did you type a name in?